# Heroku deployment keeps building with nodejs instead of using heroku.yml

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

At a bit of a loss here. This is what I'm getting in the logs:

```
C:\Users\tzahi\Documents\my-app>git push heroku heroku-fixes-and-repo-cleanup:master
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 343 bytes | 343.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. heroku/nodejs
remote:        2. https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git
remote:        3. https://github.com/appositum/heroku-buildpack-youtube-dl.git
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
```

I can post the full logs if necessary, but it seems to go wrong with "Node.js app detected."

Here's what my root folder looks like (note that Procfile is missing):

```
root
│--heroku.yml
│--Dockerfile.heroku
│--app.json
│--package.json
│   ...
```

app.json:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "description": "blah blah blah",
    "repository": "https://github.com/Tzahi12345/my-app",
    "stack": "container",
    "logo": "https://i.imgur.com/GPzvPiU.png",
    "keywords": ["youtube-dl", "youtubedl-material", "nodejs"]
}
```

heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile.heroku
  run:
   web: npm start
```

Not sure if the `run` part is necessary but I've kept it in there for now (doesn't seem to change much on this front).

Dockerfile.heroku:

```
FROM tzahi12345/my-app:my-tag
```

I have tried:

- Removing `"stack": "container"` from app.json
- Running `heroku set:stack container`
- Running this deploy link from the relevant branch: `https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/Tzahi12345/my-app`
- Praying to the heroku gods

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. I assumed that if I had the heroku.yml file in the root directory and `"stack": "container"` in the `app.json` it would detect that it's a Docker container and build appropriately. Any thoughts/suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks :)

EDIT:

Perhaps I should be clear about my end goal here. I would like to give users the ability to deploy the app using a link in the repository, and have the build process use heroku.yml as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
heroku stack:set container
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Can't believe I missed that...